# Can the impulse response, Green's function, et al, be defined for each of the two initial conditions of the wave equation?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, distribution-theory, wave-equation, greens-function, fundamental-solution

The 1D homogeneous wave equation is

$$u_{xx}(x,t)-\frac{1}{c^2} u_{tt}(x,t)=0$$

or more briefly, define the wave equation operator L as

$$L(u)\equiv u_{xx}(x,t)-\frac{1}{c^2} u_{tt}(x,t)$$

Then the wave equation is

$$L(u)=0 $$

Initial conditions are
$$u(x,0)=f(x) $$
$$u_t(x,t)|_{t=0}=g(x) $$

Then the impulse response is normally defined by the non homogeneous equation

$$ L(u)=\delta $$

$$f=g=0$$

**My question is** *Can the impulse response be defined in the homogeneous equation for each of the initial conditions?*

For example--

for the displacement impulse response:

$$L(u)=0$$ 
$$f=\delta$$ 
$$g=0$$

for the velocity impulse response:

$$L(u)=0$$ 
$$f=0$$ 
$$g=\delta$$

Then the output could be found for other initial conditions by convolution.

Comment: Very minor point: you can write $u_t(x,t)|_{t=0}=g(x)$ simply as $u_t(x,0)=g(x)$.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. When I read the term *impulse response*, I think of a system with an input and output, and the impulse response is the output (response) to a unit impulse input. From the introductory section of your question, it looks like $u(x,t)$ is the system output, and the inhomogeneous term is the input. But, in your examples section, you're suggesting setting the *output* at time zero to be an impulse, $u(x,0)=\delta$, to find an impulse *response*??

Comment: @AlfredCentauri f and g are initial conditions.  So in a sense they are inputs.  Note that the example equations are homogeneous.

Comment: Might [math.se] be better suited for this maths question?

Comment: Math mods: please merge.